# Adding mandatory fields to a paypal donation form?

Tags: donations

I am designing a donation form for a political campaign. Usually, with a donation paypal link, I do not require specific information about the user. However, with political campaign donations, there are laws that I need to observe.

I cannot seem to find information on how to add some mandatory fields to my form and still have a paypal submit option. I need to know the person's name, address, phone number, and business name.

Ideas?

Comment: What technologies / programming languages / software are you using and what does the code you have look like? SO is about programming, so if you are not actually programming, you should try a different site, like [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: I am using Dreamweaver and raw html to make the form. I am not proficient in programming. I was hoping that somebody could show me some hidden codes to add new mandatory fields to the paypal donation form.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "paypal donation form", but it seems to be a feature provided by paypal. Since you are not programming the server side, you cannot add any input fields which they did not provide. If you did somehow, they would not be saved anywhere. All you can do is ask PayPal whether they support political donations and how. Or use a different service for donations.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal's documentation describes how to add one or more text fields to a donation button [link to doc](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/get-started/donate-button-text-field)

But a heads up - we've been using this successfully for  years and just recently we have been getting an increasing number of transactions where this field is not being sent through to the transaction detail. We suspect that it may be that paypal has been streamlining their donation flow and are no longer recognizing these added fields.